# Make htaccess RewriteRule ignore certain folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use a rule like this in my htaccess file so that I can have pretty URLs:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

It works just fine, but also affects the two real subfolders I have in there images/ and blog/.  it makes it so I can't get any pictures on my site and my blog is broken.  How can I ignore those folders?

At first i figured I would just write this and have less pretty URLs:

RewriteRule ^(.*)_category/ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

But I know there are RewriteConds that will make the "_category" uneccessary, I just don't seem to be able to write it out right.  I've been reading the apache docs but it's a bit over my head.  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I just needed to use:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ category.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

I'm answering it here in case anyone stumbles across it via google.